# Javascript to show cursor when window is not full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide cursor when my window get full width and once I click on esc key button my mouse cursor start appearing.

I am using following code to show/ hide cursor  and to show window full width.

```
 function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
            elem.requestFullScreen();
             document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // to hide cursor
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // to hide cursor
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // to hide cursor
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // to hide cursor
        }
    } else{
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; // to show cursor
        console.log('test');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.body)">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    BACKGROUND: #000080;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Comment: what kind of error , you are getting ?

Comment: What do you mean by `once i click on exc button`? Are you talking about pressing the Escape key on your keyboard, or is there a button on the page?

Comment: Nevermind--I think you mean the Escape key. Answer incoming... ;D

Comment: @ihemant360 there is no error but I am not achieving the desired result.
I want when I press on esc key my cursor appear on screen. (and it is not working. I cannot see the cursor)

Comment: Try this function in your else statement `function esckey(e) {
    var x = e.keyCode;
    if (x == 27) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
}`   with `onkeydown` event

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to hook onto the `fullscreenchange` event, then check the `document.fullscreenElement`.

The basic idea is that `checkFullscreen` will run no matter how the user gets into or out of fullscreen mode, so this will allow you to hide/show the cursor whenever that changes.

There are a few ways of hooking into events, but I'll stick with the method you're using in your code already, for simplicity.

```
<body onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.body)" onfullscreenchange="checkFullscreen"></body>

function toggleFullscreen(elem) { // simplified
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  }
  else {
    document.exitFullscreen(); // changed
  }
}

function checkFullscreen() { // added
  if (document.fullScreenElement) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
  }
}
```

You'll have to add in the browser prefix stuff, but this should point you in the right direction. You can find out more on the MDN page for [fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Prefixing).

Comment: i have tried above code to open new window which will be shown in full width . so i have added  the above code on 
<body onload="toggleFullScreen(document.body)" ></body>
but it is not wokring it opens the new window but it is not shown in full width. (like we can see when we press f11)

Comment: Oh. You're not fullscreening something in the current window? You probably can't fullscreen onload, otherwise people could spam the user with unwanted ads in fullscreen mode.

Just to test, have you tried it as-is, for the current window? If that works, we can start figuring out how to make it work with a new window, if that's necessary.